# Cant I spawn a new thread to handle a new UDP "connection"?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server, udp

I know UDP is connection-less, but could I spawn a new thread to handle new UDP clients that connect to my server?

I'm trying to do this basically:

```
void *handle_connection(void *param)
{
    // read data
    ret = recvfrom(..,0,..);
}


// Wait for connection using MSG_PEEK
ret = recvfrom(.., MSG_PEEK,..);

// New thread to handle client connection
pthread_t conn_thread;
ret = pthread_create(..., handle_connection);
```

Is there a way to stablish a UDP "connection" for each client and fork off a new thread to handle it like it's done by OpenSSL when using DTLS?

With OpenSSL I can use DTLS_listen() to wait for a UDP client to connect and then start a new thread, pass the UDP socket to that thread and use usual read/write operations. For that to work though, you have to do a couple of extra bind() and connect() calls on the udp sockets.

I tried the same approach here and just ended up opening a new thread for each datagram received from the client on the server.

Comment: Can you? Why not? You can spawn new threads to do whatever you want.

Comment: You can; it's not clear that there is any benefit to doing so, however.  A single thread can handle any number of UDP clients using a single socket.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You can in OpenSSL when wrapping your socket around BIO and SSL objects...So I was wondering if the same could be done here.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work (distributing the datagrams to the threads) just to make things a lot worse (you have to change threads every time you change which connections you're working on). Why would you want to do this? We go to a lot of trouble to undo this with TCP using things like epoll and IOCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done. But I'm not sure what the guarantees are.

The basic idea is:

1. Create server socket, set `SO_REUSEADDR` on it, bind it to the
   server    port, and wait to receive data on it.
2. `recvfrom` gives you the next received datagram and the address from
   which it was sent.
3. Pass the initial datagram and the address to a new thread.
4. In the new thread, create a new socket, (again with `SO_REUSEADDR` and bind it). Now `connect` the new socket to the peer address.
5. Back to step 2

The idea here is that you always keep one "unconnected" socket. When you get a new peer, you create a new socket that is connected to that peer. When a socket is specifically connected to a remote peer, the kernel will deliver an incoming datagram from that peer to that socket. Otherwise, it will deliver the datagram to the unconnected socket.

The thing I'm not 100% sure about is: Does the OS *guarantee* to deliver a subsequent datagram only to the connected socket instead of to the unconnected socket? It does make sense that it would work this way and it seems to work on my linux box -- see python3 code below (can use `nc -u localhost 9999` as client).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from threading import Thread
import socket

def client_thread(addr, msg):
    # Create a new socket and connect it to the peer.
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 9999))   # Maybe omit -- see below
    sock.connect(addr)
    # Maybe set SO_RCVTIMEO to cause timeout on receive and 
    # cause client thread to bail?
    while True:
        sock.send(msg)
        msg = sock.recv(1024)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', 9999))

threads = []

while True:
    # Receive datagram on unconnected socket
    msg, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    # Send connected socket and datagram
    th = Thread(target=client_thread, args=(addr, msg))
    th.start()
    threads.append(th)
```

You would presumably have some way of killing off the sub-threads eventually so that they don't hang around forever if your client disappears.

Alternatively, you could omit binding the new socket in `client_thread`, which will cause the kernel to choose an unused port for the local address in the new socket, but then the client would need to pay attention to the address from which it received the initial response and direct future datagrams to that address. This would accomplish the same thing and in many ways be cleaner.

The client side could be something like this (again using python for demonstration):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket

# Initial request sent to well-known port
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
addr = ('localhost', 9999)

for n in range(5):
    print('Send to {}'.format(addr))
    sock.sendto(b'Hello', addr)
    response, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    # Subsequent requests sent to whoever responded to last request
    print('Got response {} from {}'.format(response, addr))
```